# Foam on bottom of monitor motherboard

Tags: display, board, monitor

I am currently trying to repair my LG 27MP35 monitor and came across these foam blocks on the bottom of the motherboard:

[image]
[image]
[image]

At first I thought they were just something like spacers, but then it didn't really make sense because there are some contacts on the bottom of the board that they were glued to:

[image]
[image]

I don't have any idea what those are. They seem to also make contact with the back of the screen but I don't know what for.

[image]

My monitor is still not working and I want to know if these could be part of the problem. It seems like they have something to do with the problem because ater I replaced the mainboard of the monitor today and the screen was still not working, I noticed that these foam things were missing so I put them in place and it was working again. But now it's not working anymore even with the foam in place. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you describe "not working"?

Comment: @Bort It's not turning on. At first it used to always go into standby or power saving mode randomly (while using my PC) so that I was not able to turn it back on without removing the power and wating ~5-15 minutes, usually. Then some day I was not able to turn it on anymore at all. I already tried switching the power supply but that didn't change anything

Comment: Not easy to see it on the pictures, could it be zebra strips? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector

Comment: They may be for heat sinking. I have seen similar foam blocks used in a Dell monitor that were obviously to help get the heat out (connecting physical heat sinks to the inner shield metal). If they appear to be directly opposite devices that dissipate a lot of power, that would be a good indication. You can also check and see if they are conductive or not using your DMM on the highest ohms range.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany They definitely are not below any devices that could need heat sinking. I made some continuity tests as you suggested; The foam inside is not conductive but it has a conductive outer layer and as I said it makes contact with the metallic case of the screen.

Comment: @Bread123 Then it is probably just for shielding- EMI foam.

Comment: The foam may be attached to metal for mechanical purposes only, maybe thermal or maybe just for spacing. The designers could have put a metal pad on the board for the sole purpose of guiding assemblers for foam placement. Without fully vetting the design there is no way to know. Regardless, they probably don't have anything to do with the *operation* of the monitor, you should be able to run it on the bench. There is probably a bigger problem or a loose connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conductive pads allow electrical connections between sub-assemblies. A foam core is covered with a conductive "fabric":
[image: conductive flexible pads]
 <strike>Be very careful that the aquadag coating on the cathode-ray-tube is grounded...one or more of these pads might be used to make this ground connection to the CRT. Aquadag is the dull black/grey coating painted on much of the glass surface of the CRT. Ungrounded aquadag is electrically dangerous - high voltages are involved.</strike>

Comment: The OP has a 27"  IPS (In Plane Switching) LCD monitor with LED backlight. No CRT, or even CCFL backlight. ;-)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Tnks, "LG" should've been a givaway. Perhaps the LG 27MP35 LCD mounting frame needs grounding for static-protection reasons.

Comment: They do look just like that

Comment: You're probably right about it being conductive foam- we use some similar foam for EMI control.